# Replace within a string, Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I am having some issues with the simple .replace() function from JS.

Here is my code

```
    console.log(URL);
    URL.replace("-","/");
    console.log(URL);
```

Here is my output:

folder1-folder2-folder3
folder1-folder2-folder3

the second one should be

folder1/folder2/folder3

right?

If you guys need from my code, please let me know :)

Thanks in advance,

Bram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: [*"The `replace()` method **returns a new string** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct thing is to replace it with a global regex with `g` after the regex that in this case is `/-/`

```
console.log(URL);
URL = URL.replace(/-/g,"/");
console.log(URL);
```

Comment: Hmm, it worked, why didnt Rajesh option worked?

And why does it work like you say? What does the "regex" do?

Comment: regex is a regular expression that matchs patterns and with string `replace` method you can replace any ocurrence with something that you want, `g` regex modifier is to match all the ocurrence while normally would replace only the first one [Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Replace returns a new string after replacement.  It does not alter the string that `replace` was called on. Try this:

```
console.log(URL);
URL = URL.replace("-","/");
console.log(URL);
```

To replace all occurences look at this [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

```
console.log(URL);
URL = URL.replace(/-/g, '/');
console.log(URL);
```

Comment: Some progress, but now I get:

folder1/folder2-folder3

Comment: @B.Wesselink you will have to use regex. `URL = URL.replace(/-/g,"/");`

Comment: Now I get an "undefined"